# What characters are valid for Active Directory groups?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server

My software program is going to auto-generate Active Directory group names. We need to know which characters aren't allowed in an AD Group name (i.e. `/, \, [, \, |,` etc.).

I found this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/909264) from Microsoft explaining the valid names for computers, domains, sites, and OUs, but not specifically for groups.

The AD server environment is 2008, but I'd like to make the group validation targeting down to 2003.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> The names of security principal objects can contain all Unicode characters except the special LDAP characters defined in RFC 2253. This list of special characters includes: a leading space; a trailing space; and any of the following characters: # , + " \ < > ;

Max. size for Group name:

> 63 characters, or 63 bytes depending upon the character set; individual characters may require more than one byte.

Special Limitations:

> A group account cannot consist solely of numbers, periods (.), or spaces. Any leading periods or spaces are cropped.

- [MS Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc776019(v=ws.10).aspx)
- [RFC 2253](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2253.txt)